# How To Create A High Performance Selectors [no jquery please]

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, unobtrusive-javascript

I m a JavaScript pure developer i design my own framework when i tested my selectors module i found a very big issue which is performance

in the selectors module i don't do a very complex selector like jquery i do a simple one 
my big cause here when i run my selectors in some cases i have to get all elements on the body of the page and have to loop over them to get a specific kind of elements like TD elements for instance , note >>>> dont tell me use getElementsByTagName('TD') cause in my selectors i can make the developer select more than 1 tagName like

```
getElementsByTagNames('td,tr')
```

so in that case i have to get all and then loop over and pic only the needed items

i found that way is very performance eater in the other hand jquery have a hilarious speed to select items doesn't jquery do loops also or what so my main question here

how to do a high performed selectors using JavaScript 
:)

thanks

Comment: *Why* are you creating your own selector engine? You can take a look at the [uncompressed source of Sizzle.js that is used by jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js) to see what they use for high performance. Personally, I don't think many javascript-based methods can beat browser's native implementations like `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @DCoder Becuase i need to take that experiance making my own selectors engine :)

Comment: @Marwan In that case you should start working on an actual selector engine instead of making useless dom helper functions :P

Comment: @Esailija mmm i will think about it but in my case i incest taking that experiance :P

Answer (score 7):

> doesn't jquery do loops also or what

jQuery is smart enough to use an existing selector library (sizzle.js).

Sizzle [is smart enough](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L1327) to let the browser do the work. `document.querySelectorAll` does the trick.

<sub>edit: actually, sizzle.js used to be inherent part of jquery, but is a separate project now</sub>

Comment: +1 thanks very much i didnt know that there is a document.querySelectorAll i will search on it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can still use `getElementsByTagName` if you do something like this:

```
function getElementsByTagNames(elements) {
    elements = elements.split(",");
    var foundElements = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i<len; i++) {
        foundElements.push(document.getElementsByTagName(elements[i]));
    }
    return foundElements;
}
```

Now if you call `getElementsByTagNames("tr,div")`, an array containing all `tr` and `div` elements will be returned.

Comment: It returns an array of nodelists, which is very unintuitive. in 99.99% of use cases the user would have to flatten the array anyway.

Comment: Plus it doesn't maintain the original node order.

Comment: Good points. I was just providing a starting point for the OP, though, not writing him a custom selector library. :-)

Comment: +1 its a nice job Elliot i just though using getElementsByTagName over and over in a loop can make a performance load but its ok :)